# Can I use the word "persons"?

Tags: grammatical-number

I hope this is the correct place for my question. I didn't post in English learner site because it seems a more specific question.
As everyone knows the plural of person is *people*, but I saw in a menu

> Starter for 4 **persons**

I was sure about the error, but a friend told me that sometimes in menus and lists it can be used if there is a fixed number.

What is your opinion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The plural of *person* is not *people*, it is *persons*.  That being said, however, it is not common to use persons except in certain cases.  One case is your example, when specifying a particular number of persons.  You could say "Starter for 4 persons" or "Starter for 4 people", although in the context of a restaurant menu, it would (in my opinion) be slightly less awkward-sounding to use *persons* rather than *people*.  The word people is more of a collective.  You would never say "The persons of the United Kingdom" but always "The people of the United Kingdom" when speaking collectively.  But if being severely formal, you might say about a distinct group of people who hail from the UK: "All United Kingdom persons must check in with their consulate upon arrival."  It would be awkward-sounding to use *people* in that sentence.

From [Collins World English Dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/person?s=t) (cited on Reference.com)

> person  (ˈpɜːs ə n) — n  , pl persons
>
> 1. an individual human being
> 2. the body of a human being, sometimes including his or her clothing: guns hidden on his person
> 3. a grammatical category into which pronouns and forms of verbs are subdivided depending on whether they refer to the speaker, the person
>      addressed, or some other individual, thing, etc
> 4. a human being or a corporation recognized in law as having certain rights and obligations
> 5. (philosophy)  a being characterized by consciousness, rationality, and a moral sense, and traditionally thought of as consisting of both
>      a body and a mind or soul
> 6. (archaic)  a character or role; guise
> 7. in person - (a) actually present: the author will be there in person ; (b) without the help or intervention of others
>
> **Usage** "People" is the word usually used to refer to more than one individual: there were a hundred people at the reception. "Persons" 
>   is rarely used, except in official English: *several persons were
>   interviewed*

Comment: Personages can be used if you want to be extra severely formal: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/personage

Answer (score 3):

The plural of *[person](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/person_1)* is *people* or *persons* (more formal). The usage in the menu is certainly correct.

Answer (score 1):

There is no basis for asserting persons is better formal English than people. The Oxford notes its use in formal settings but, unlike Merriam-Webster, does not advocate it:

> ...Persons, on the other hand, tends now to be restricted to official or formal contexts, as in this vehicle is authorized to carry twenty persons; no persons admitted without a pass.

([Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/person))

Comment: Where in M-W is that mentioned? Do you have a link?

Comment: @Mitch the answer is quoting the Oxford and Ive edited the answer

Comment: @user OK, I misunderstood. But Paul still refers to M-W, so it would be nice to have a link there. Paul, could you please provide it?

Comment: @Mitch I think the better thing to do is vote this q as a duplicate. See my comment to the OP.

Comment: @user You should VTC that way then